# What is Facebook session_key for?

Tags: facebook

I develop facebook app, with oauth 2.0 beta. But, usually i don't get signed_request, but session parameter with session_key, So what is session_key for?

Answer (score 0):

session_keys were used before OAuth access tokens were implemented.  These will soon be deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ so basically you don't need to worry about them moving forward.